# Jcurses ExceptionInInitializerError в чем проблема

Tags: java, intellij-idea, библиотеки

Добавил `jcurses` как надо, `.jar`, `src`, `doc`. Нативы тоже добавил. Почему возникает проблема в `InputChar`?

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at jcurses.system.InputChar.<clinit>(InputChar.java:13)
    at net.slashie.libjcsi.jcurses.JCursesConsoleInterface.<clinit>(JCursesConsoleInterface.java:282)
    at ru.xahon.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jcurses.system.Toolkit.getLibraryPath(Toolkit.java:111)
    at jcurses.system.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:37)
    ... 3 more
```

---

хотел подключить библиотеку для roguelike игр `libjsci`

Comment: попробуйте положить `.dll`-файл рядом с `jcurses.jar` или запускать jvm с ключом `-Dlibrary.path=путь_к_папке_с_dll`

Comment: Или попробуйте breakpoint поставить в [`jcurses.system.Toolkit.getLibraryPath`](https://github.com/sunhong/jcurses/blob/master/src/jcurses/system/Toolkit.java#L95)  и посмотреть, где он пытается найти эти либы.

Comment: @zRrr `.so` мне нужен, т.к. linux, но они и так рядом лежат. Сейчас попробую остальное

Comment: @zRrr поставил бряк, путь к либе какой-то странный `/home/ilia/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b/Curses/jcurses/lib`. Изменил на английский, все равно